# Java Swing. JTextPane. Getting start and end character seen by user

Tags: java, string, swing, user-interface, code-editor

I creating an IDE for C++ on Java. I have already set up code highlighting, bracket matching etc. This IDE highlights cartan keywords, but when working with long documents it's getting slow because it finds keywords in whole document, not in range seen by user. How to get range of text seen by user in `javax.swing.JTextPane`.

Comment: `.viewToModel2D(Point2D p)` should be what you need

Comment: @JuanCarlos: it is a duplicate except that the method used in Rob Camick's answer, `viewToModel` has since been deprecated in favor of the method that I've given in my comment above.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels that's nice but is worth to mention that it has been deprecated [since java 9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#viewToModel-java.awt.Point-), and we don't know the version the OP is working on.

Comment: @JuanCarlosMendoza: good point!